# .htaccess with a `#` in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, urlencode

I would like to map `/tagged/c#` to `/?tagged=c#` on my website. Obviously, the `#` won't be seen by the server, so I URL encode it to `%23`. Here's the .htaccess I'm using:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tagged/(.*)$ /?tagged=$1 [NC]
```

As you'd expect, this works, passing a query of `C#`:

```
/?tagged=C%23
```

Yet these don't, all giving passing  query of `C`

```
/tagged/C%23
/tagged/C%23moretextthatgetslost
```

I assume the `#` is being interpreted as a literal hash, so is lost somewhere along the way.

What do I need to do to make these second cases work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I need to use the [`[B]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b) flag:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tagged/(.*)$ /?tagged=$1 [NC,B]
```

Paraphrasing the documentation:

> With the B flag, it will instead map `/C%2b%2b` to `/index.php?show=/C%2b%2b`.